# String replace does not work in javascript (with double quotes)

Tags: javascript, string, replace, double-quotes

Please look at the following code, If i do not perform the "Sanitary" steps in the function the code does not replace the  string values.

can some one help me understand this?

Complete code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function replaceString(orgStr,oldStr,newStr){

//############# Sanitary Steps #############//
oldStr = oldStr .replace(/[ ]+/g,"$");
oldStr = oldStr .replace(/[$]+/g," ");
orgStr = orgStr .replace(/[ ]+/g,"$");
orgStr = orgStr .replace(/[$]+/g," ");
newStr = newStr .replace(/[ ]+/g,"$");
newStr = newStr .replace(/[$]+/g," ");
//############# Sanitary Steps #############//

orgStr = orgStr.replace(oldStr,newStr);
if(orgStr.indexOf(oldStr) != -1){
orgStr = replaceString(orgStr,oldStr,newStr)
}
return orgStr;
}
var fields = ['"Employee Expense Facts"."Total Expense"','"Expense Amount by Expense Type Facts"."Airfare Expense Amount"'];
var selectedField = 0;
var selectedField = 0;
var qry = 'SELECT rcount(1) s_0, "Employee Expenses"."Time"."Date" s_1, "Employee Expenses"."Employee Expense Facts"."Total Expense" s_2 FROM "Employee Expenses" WHERE ("Employee Expense Facts"."Total Expense" IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY 1, 2 ASC NULLS LAST WHERE ("Employee Expense Facts"."Total Expense" IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY 1, 2 ASC NULLS LAST';
qry = qry .replace(/[\n\t\r]+/g," ");
var qry2 = replaceString(qry,""+fields[0],""+fields[1]);
console.log(qry2);

</script>
```

Help me understand why I need to perform those sanitary steps???
I found the solution by just trial and error method.

Comment: Uh oh, SQL-Query in Javascript ... meep meep meep ... you have turned on the selfdestruction mode.

Comment: What were you trying to do originally? Also it seems as if you construct an SQL statement in the browser which will probably be executed on a server, which is a huge no-no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advise would be: Throw away all that code!

Now start again, handing the data from the client to the server via a normal formsubmit or an ajax call. Now process them serverside.

And always remember rule number one:

**1) You can never trust all users to behave the way YOU want.**

Thats why never ever create your SQL clientside!

Comment: I am working with OBIEE webservices  to get the SQL and change them using a fixed logic. User never even gets to see the SQL or alter it in any way.

Comment: That's what you might think, but every experienced user can fake those requests pretty easily altering the sql the way they want to.

Answer (score 0):

The Issue is in the SQL itself:

```
SELECT rcount(1) s_0,
       "Employee Expenses"."Time"."Date" s_1,
       "Employee Expenses"."Employee Expense Facts"."Total Expense" s_2 
FROM   "Employee Expenses" 
WHERE ("Employee Expense Facts"."Total Expense" IS NOT NULL)
       ORDER BY 1, 2 ASC NULLS LAST 
WHERE ("Employee Expense Facts"."Total Expense" IS NOT NULL)
       ORDER BY 1, 2 ASC NULLS LAST
```

I found out that there are  double quotes which even after using escape characters are not replaced. I have tried replacing the (") with special characters and then performing the string replace and yet not able to do that successfully.

**Whats surprising is if you  create this function on the local HTML file  this works without sanitary code.  but when i upload the same code on the server it does not work. for that i had to put in place the sanitary lines.**

If any one else figures out why this is caused please do let me know :)

thanks
vx

Comment: You could post this as another question in order to get some helpful answers. Users most likely won't visit a question with two (accepted) answers.